# Codename One - Video Capture

Tags: java, android, codenameone

Am using codename one to capture the video and upload it to Vimeo.
But I get errors when I click the button. What am I doing wrong ?

**I get below error when the method is called.**
I have a camera
java.lang.NullPointerException
at userclasses.StateMachine$1.actionPerformed(StateMachine.java:63)

```
protected void onMain_Button1Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    Capture.captureVideo(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {    

            if(Capture.hasCamera()){
                System.out.println("I have a camera");
            }else{
                System.out.println("I don't have a camera");
            }

        try {
            String path = (String) evt.getSource();
            Log.p("Path->" + path);
            Vimeo.MyVimeo(path);
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 63 in the code below?

Comment: This is the one.

            String path =
(String) evt.getSource();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event can be null if the operation is canceled.

Comment: I have selected a video file WMV to upload, which is not supported I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You are not meant to select a file, The capture class is for capturing media files from the device. It brings out FileChooser if you are using the emulator, therefore test it on a device and see how it works.